# How does a web application get database updates and propagate updates to web clients using server sent events?

Tags: java, database, servlets, server-sent-events

If a Java-based web application needs to update clients based on a database record update using server sent events, are there ways to getting the database updates via a callback mechanism from a database to a servlet so that a java servlet does not need to continuously poll a database to detect for updates?

Comment: Do you have a code example of what are you saying?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the JDBC specification (that I know of) that will allow you to do this. If at all, this is a database-specific functionality. Oracle supports such functionality starting Oracle 11g:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm